# Sourcing a tagged terraform module in Azure DevOps Git Repo

Tags: azure-devops, terraform

Trying to source a terraform module from a git repo in Azure DevOps.

This works, and pulls the code from the master branch

module "my_module" {

```
      source ="git::https://dev.azure.com/company/project/_git/MyModules//module1"

    }
```

This doesn't work, and instead redirects me to the webpage.

```
    module "my_module" {

      source ="git::https://dev.azure.com/company/project/_git/MyModules//module1?ref=GT1.0"

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I import a public repo https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-ecs.git into Azure DevOps Git

```
module "ecs" {
  source = "git::https://dev.azure.com/xxxxxxxx/terraform-aws-ecs/_git/terraform-aws-ecs?ref=v1.0.0"

  name = "my-ecs"
}
```

I can get the package without issue

```
$ terraform get
- module.ecs
  Getting source "git::https://dev.azure.com/xxxxxxxx/terraform-aws-ecs/_git/terraform-aws-ecs?ref=v1.0.0"
```

Comment: Strange. I'm doing the exact same thing and doesn't work
   

    `Error loading modules: error downloading 'https://dev.azure.com/company/project/_git/MyModules?ref=v1.0': C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe exited with 1: error: pathspec 'v1.0' did not match any file(s) known to git`

Comment: Is there a release or tag named `v1.0` or just `1.0`? Use the command `git tag` to show all tags and make sure `v1.0` is in the output